# Is it possible to convert Base& to Derived& without object copying or undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, casting, reference, polymorphism, undefined-behavior

Problem: I have a class (PortableFoo) designed to be very portable. It contains a scoped class PortableBar. The surrounding codebase (call it Client A) requires both Foo and Bar to have a function that cannot be implemented portably, and Foo's implementation must call Bar's implementation. The following is a solution that compiles and works in GCC, but I know invokes undefined behavior when it casts the reference from base to derived:

```
//Code in portable codebase
class PortableFoo
{
public:
    int a = 1;
    class PortableBar
    {
    public:
        int b = 1;
    } bar;
};

//Code in Client A
#include <iostream>
class AdaptedFoo: public PortableFoo
{
public:
    int fancy_foo_func()
    {
        return a + ((AdaptedBar&)bar).fancy_bar_func();
    }
    
    class AdaptedBar: public PortableBar
    {
    public:
        int fancy_bar_func()
        {
            return b;
        }
    };
};

int main()
{
    AdaptedFoo foo;
    std::cout<<foo.fancy_foo_func(); //prints "2"
    return 0;
}
```

As in the example, it's no issue for me to simply construct objects as AdaptedFoo in the first place in ClientA, the problem is that AdaptedFoo.bar is still of type PortableBar. I know of three solutions to the problem but each have significant drawbacks:

1. The above solution, with an undefined behavior reference cast that may cause a segmentation fault if `sizeof(AdaptedBar) != sizeof(PortableBar)`. (In the real codebase, I have tested that it *always* causes a segmentation fault if there's a size mismatch, because I actually store a vector of Bars. The minimal example is not quite complex enough for the segfault to show up.)
2. Make fancy_bar_func() virtual with an empty implementation in PortableBar. This is only a solution to the minimal example, my real problem has the additional complication that fancy_bar_func() must be templated, and templated functions cannot be virtual. (Specifically, it is the serialize() function used by Boost Serialization - the third party library demands it be a templated function.)
3. Give AdaptedBar a constructor with the signature AdaptedBar(PortableBar&), allowing temporaries of type AdaptedBar to be constructed from references to PortableBar. The problem is that such a temporary must copy all the members of PortableBar, and in the real world, PortableBar is an extremely large object, so making temporary copies during serialization isn't suitable.

**Question:** Since solutions 2 and 3 fail compilation and system requirements respectively, the undefined behavior is my only known valid solution right now. Are there other approaches I'm missing that do not invoke UB?

Comment: How should that work? `bar` is always an instance of type `PortableBar` because it's neither a pointer nor a reference (so you will always run into slicing even if you assign a different object). The only well defined casts on that member would be up-casts. Everything else will be UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ran into one of the main reason why public member variables are a bad idea.

If all access to the class goes through functions, overloading the accessors to return adapters that wrap a reference to the underlying member would be a transparent refactor, and would give you Mostly what you want.

Like so:

```
class PortableFoo
{
public:
  class PortableBar
  {
  public:
    int b = 1;
  };

  int get_a() { return a;}
  bar& get_bar() { return bar;}

  private:
    int a = 1;
    PortableBar bar;
};

class AdaptedFoo : public PortableFoo
{
public:    
    class AdaptedBar
    {
        PortableFoo::PortableBar& bar;

    public:
        AdaptedBar(PortableFoo::PortableBar& src_bar) : bar(src_bar) {}
        int fancy_bar_func()
        {
            return bar.b;
        }
    };

    int get_a() { return a;}
    AdaptedBar get_bar() {return AdaptedBar{PortableFoo::get_bar()};}
    
    int fancy_foo_func()
    {
        return a + get_bar().fancy_bar_func();
    }
};
```

Comment: Excellent point, thank you - this approach both solves the general problem and (happily) meets my myriad weird requirements.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to convert Base& to Derived& without object copying or undefined behavior?

Yes, it is possible on a condition that the base reference refers to a base sub object of dynamic type `Derived`. A minimal example:

```
struct Base{};
struct Derived : Base{};

Derived  d;
Base&    bref = d;
Derived& dref = static_cast<Derived&>(bref); // OK, no copy
```

If the condition isn't satisifed, then it isn't possible.

---

As for solution to your problem, when you're dealing with inheritance and polymorphism, the answer is invariably: Use virtual functions:

```
struct PortableFoo
{
    int a = 1;
    struct PortableBar
    {
        int b = 1;
    };

    virtual PortableBar& bar() = 0;
};

struct AdaptedFoo: PortableFoo
{
    int fancy_foo_func()
    {
        return a + bar().fancy_bar_func();       
    }

    virtual AdaptedBar& bar() override {
        return abar;
    };

private:
    struct AdaptedBar: PortableBar
    {
        int fancy_bar_func()
        {
            return b;
        }
    } abar;
};
```

Comment: Look at how `bar` is defined. How do you get a object of a derived type in there?

Comment: @Timo By changing the definition.

Comment: Re: your virtual function solution, +1 because it's likely helpful to many, but it sadly doesn't fit my use case because PortableFoo must have a PortableBar member independent of the needs of Client A. (And I cannot give Bar members to both PortableFoo and AdaptedFoo and use the virtual function to choose which gets returned, because PortableBar is extremely large.)

Answer (score 0):

For those who get here on a search about Boost Serialization, I've discovered a solution specific to that problem: do not bother with deriving the class at all, because the function required is technically portable.

Adding a single forward declaration to the top of the file makes the following code required by the library 100% portable:

```
namespace boost{namespace serialization{ class access;}}
class PortableBar
{
    private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        // archive statements with operators &, <<, >>
    }
}
```

This is because the function is templated, meaning it is never compiled at all if it's never called. Only Client A has any calls to serialize(), so only when compiling Client A is PortableBar::serialize<some_archive_type>() compiled, and at that point the necessary Boost headers will be available.

In hindsight, this was likely a very intentional choice by the library author, and my frustration with being unable to make the function virtual was because they had actually supplied an even nicer way to use the library in portable code.